# iPad iWebkit css question (form field)

Tags: css, ipad

i don't have any knowledge about the iwebkit, or something similar, but i have to make a form, and i really don't know where to start.

Here is an image of what i want to do, what i ask you is a little help to make the 2 first fields (name and password) using css and i can learn from that to make the rest of the form:

http://postimage.org/image/1p4izgsas/

I really appreciate any given help. Thanks very much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Sencha Touch is what you want, why not use that instead?

Comment: Sencha Touch is too elaborated for my needs, just need a single form page. Thanks anyway dave.